# JIT compilation vs Dynamic compilation

Tags: compilation, programming-languages, implementation

what's difference between JIT compilation and Dynamic compilation??

they are just same things?

in Wiki, JIT compliation is a form of Dynamic compilaiton.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_compilation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see "dynamic compilation" somehow as "superset" of what "JIT" is about.

By "definition", JIT means that, at runtime, some "engine" analyses what is going on, and based on that, it makes decision if/how to turn Java bytecode into machine code.

So: anything that a "JIT" is doing could be seen as "dynamic compiling". But not everything that might fall under "dynamic compiling" would be found in JITs.

Comment: thanks for answer. which is not found in JITs? Could you put just some examples?